# set token URI function

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft, erc721

I understood that setTokenURI function isn't in use anymore. How can I change the token URI of the NFT token I want to create?
for now my function createCollectible inside the smart contract looks like this:

```
function createCollectible(string memory tokenURI)
    public
    returns (uint256)
{
    uint256 newItemId = tokenId;
    _safeMint(msg.sender, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
    tokenId = tokenId + 1;
    return newItemId;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_setTokenURI` is still used but it is moved to the `ERC721URIStorage`. Here is the [openzeppelin link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol)

When you create your contract, you should inherit:

```
contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage { }
```

Since calling it an expensive operation, team wants you to use `tokenUri` function in `ERC721`:

```
function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721Metadata: URI query for nonexistent token");

        string memory baseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString())) : "";
    }
```

this is `_baseUri()` which is inherited from `ERC721`. It is `virtual` so that you can `override` it inside `ERC721URIStorage` and change it from "" to anything you want.

```
function _baseURI() internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return "";
    }
```

this time you need to inherit from `ERC721`

```
 contract NFT is ERC721{
    function _setTokenURI(uint256 tokenId, string memory _tokenURI) internal virtual {
       require(_exists(tokenId), "...");
       _tokenURIs[tokenId] = _tokenURI;
           }
   }
```

They both have different use cases: [Discussed Here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/why-doesnt-openzeppelin-erc721-contain-settokenuri/6373/34)

Comment: So I need to use in my smart contract tokenURI function from ERC721 or setTokenURI from the ERC721URIstorage?

Comment: either of them. each has its own use case and discussed here: https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/why-doesnt-openzeppelin-erc721-contain-settokenuri/6373/34

Comment: Thanks. Another question is why _setTokenURI is more expensive that tokenURI as you mentioned above?

Comment: ERC721URIstorage stores data for tokenURI on-chain @OmerS , this might be one of the reason.

Comment: _exists(tokenId) method was removed from openzeppelin 5 and should be replaced with ```_ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0)```. so answer is outdated